# CoreData Test Data?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

I am working with CoreData in my iPhone app and I need a couple of hundred records to test with, but adding this many manually in the app after every clean build I do will take me a life time. Are there any solutions that will let me somehow inject a bunch of data for testing with?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an In-Memory Data Store may be useful for testing. The data in the store only lasts for the lifecycle of the app. If you need test data, is there something that you're looking for that's more complicated than writing a "insertTestData" method that is nothing more than a for-loop that inserts a specific number of entities into the persistent store with random attribute values?